# How to add commit hash into reactjs vite.config.js

Tags: reactjs, vite

I want to add commit hash into my react app. Normally, I added it with webpack but this project they are using vite.config.js. May I know how to inject commit hash into vite and how can I use it in react component.

Thanks.

const commitHash = require('child_process').execSync('git rev-parse --short HEAD').toString();

Answer (score 10):

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

const commitHash = require('child_process')
    .execSync('git rev-parse --short HEAD')
    .toString();

export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    __COMMIT_HASH__: JSON.stringify(commitHash),
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint but that command returns only '--\nshort\nHEAD\n' in my cli

Comment: @Reiner I edited the code fragment. There shouldn't have been a space between the "--" and "short".

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative to the dynamic require

```
import * as child from "child_process";

const commitHash = child.execSync("git rev-parse --short HEAD").toString();
```

Comment: And in [define](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define): `define: {'import.meta.env.VITE_APP_VERSION': JSON.stringify(commitHash)}`

Answer (score 2):

@Reiner, it is working for me. Here is tag I use in my react app.

```
<p className="text-center text-gray-500 text-xs">
    Version - {__COMMIT_HASH__}
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem was only that the command line did not read the git-command properly. ✌